# Can't add IPv4 authorized network to GCP Cloud SQL first generation

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to add an IPv4 authorized network to my  GCP Cloud SQL First Generation instance.
I can add it but it doesn't get saved (if I reload the webpage it's not there anymore).

[image: Cloud SQL trying to add authorized network in the dashboard]

See screenshot above. The edit-icon says "Unresolved items must be completed or deleted.". What kind of unresolved items could there be ? I have reserved a IPv4 address already of course.

PS. The IP posted in this screenshot is not my real one. DS.

Comment: Did you click the blue `save` button at the bottom of the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click the trash icon on the empty entry and then save.

Sorry about that, we are already working to improve this part of the UI.

Answer (score 0):

The blue "Save" button appears in the bottom of the page after you make any changes in the Authorized Networks.

You'll need to scroll down to see it.